# Django - Multiple permissions in a view

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework, permissions

I want to create a permission for a view that would verify that the user is either the owner of a shop or an admin. I have already created two permissions which work well when called separately which checks for one that the user is admin and for the other that the user is the owner of the shop. I would now like to make a global condition verifying that one of the two conditions is met.

Here are my departure conditions :

**utils.py**

```
class IsOwner(BasePermission):
    """
    Check if the user who made the request is owner.
    Use like that : permission_classes = [IsOwner]
    """
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return request.user and request.user.is_authenticated
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        try:
            user_shop = UserShop.objects.get(user=request.user, shop=obj)
            return True
        except:
            return False

class IsAdmin(BasePermission):
    """
    Check if the user who made the request is admin.
    Use like that : permission_classes = [IsAdmin]
    """
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if not 'Authorization' in request.headers:
            return False
        else:
            return request.user.is_admin

class OwnerView(GenericAPIView):
    """
    Check if a user is owner
    """
    permission_classes = (IsOwner,)

class AdminView(APIView):
    """
    Check if a user is admin
    """
    permission_classes = (IsAdmin,)
```

Here is the function I am trying to do :

```
class AdminOrOwnerView(GenericAPIView):
    """
    Check if a user is admin or owner
    """
    permission_classes = ( IsOwner|IsAdmin,)
```

Currently, this condition allows any logged in user to use my view

Here is my view :

**views.py**

```
class ShopDetail(AdminOrOwnerView):
    """Edit ou delete a shop"""
    queryset = Shop.objects.all()
    lookup_field = 'path'

    def put(self, request, path):
        """For admin or shop owner to edit a shop"""
        shop = self.get_object()
        serializer = ShopSerializer(shop, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors)
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have combined the two permissions using:

```
permission_classes = ( IsOwner|IsAdmin,)
```

What happens is first `has_permission` is called which succeeds because `IsOwner` returns `True` for a logged in user in that case. Next when `has_object_permission` is called this again succeeds because this time `IsAdmin` returns `True` (since you haven't implemented anything there).

One solution would be to again explicitly check if the user is an admin in `has_object_permission` for `IsAdmin`:

```py
class IsAdmin(BasePermission):
    """
    Check if the user who made the request is admin.
    Use like that : permission_classes = [IsAdmin]
    """
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if not 'Authorization' in request.headers:
            return False
        else:
            return request.user.is_admin
    
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return self.has_permission(request, view) # reuse `has_permission`
```